# Allow access to specific file on s3/cloudfront without key-pair

Tags: amazon-s3, cross-domain, amazon-cloudfront, http-live-streaming

I am trying to use adaptive streaming with s3/cloudfront. I have that working with the direct link, but need to use the actual http://XXXXXXX.cloudfront.net to serve it through the app. The problem is I keep getting the following on the crossdomain.xml:

```
<Error>
    <Code>MissingKey</Code>
    <Message>Missing Key-Pair-Id query parameter or cookie value</Message>
</Error>
```

I know WHY I get that, but not how to fix it or work around it. I am fine with the other files needing the key-pair, in fact we require it. I have added a crossdomain.xml file to the root of the bucket, so it should be accessible. How do I prevent it from requiring a key-pair-id to  reach that ONE file?

Answer (score 0):

Actually iot was simple... I worked on it all day yesterday, asked my question, and then figured it out, lol.

in cloudfront, I created a new origin with no auth (Restrict Viewer Access (Use Signed URLs or Signed Cookies) = no

then I created a new behavior, specified the /crossdomain.xml as the path, and gave it the new origin.

boom, done.